# KeyError while converting XML to csv

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I am new to Python Programming getting

```
 ShotCode = root.attrib['Stops']
KeyError: 'Stops'
```

Error

```
tree = ET.parse(os.path.join(folderpath, xmlfilename))
root = tree.getroot()

filename, _ = xmlfilename.rsplit('.', 1)
Shot_30AA = open(filename + '.csv', 'w', newline='')
csvwriter = csv.writer(Shot_30AA)
head = []

ShotCode = root.attrib['Stops']

csvwriter.writerow(['Stops', ShotCode])
head.append(ShotCode)
```

sample Xml:

```xml
<Stops> <cmp_name>N/A</cmp_name> <cmp_id>N/A</cmp_id> <pu_DepartureDate>N/A</pu_DepartureDate> <DeliveryName>ABC</DeliveryName> <DeliveryID>RRFF</DeliveryID> <del_DepartureDate>2021-07-26T16:01:24.647</del_DepartureDate> <WorkOrder/> <ReleaseNo>EFFC</ReleaseNo> <NetWeight>38160.00</NetWeight> <TareWeight>0</TareWeight> <baletype>OCC-BALE</baletype> <BaleCount>36.00</BaleCount> <BaleCountLBH>0</BaleCountLBH> <SupplierName>VFGP</SupplierName> <DriverCode>DERG</DriverCode> <Coments>18971852</Coments> <TruckId>18971852</TruckId> <Picture/> </Stops>
```

Comment: post your full code pls...

Comment: My guess based on the error is that you made a typo and the root of the XML document actually does not have a "Stops" attribute. In order to be sure, we kind of need a sample XML.

Comment: <Stops>
<cmp_name>N/A</cmp_name>
<cmp_id>N/A</cmp_id>
<pu_DepartureDate>N/A</pu_DepartureDate>
<DeliveryName>ABC</DeliveryName>
<DeliveryID>RRFF</DeliveryID>
<del_DepartureDate>2021-07-26T16:01:24.647</del_DepartureDate>
<WorkOrder/>
<ReleaseNo>EFFC</ReleaseNo>
<NetWeight>38160.00</NetWeight>
<TareWeight>0</TareWeight>
<baletype>OCC-BALE</baletype>
<BaleCount>36.00</BaleCount>
<BaleCountLBH>0</BaleCountLBH>
<SupplierName>VFGP</SupplierName>
<DriverCode>DERG</DriverCode>
<Coments>18971852</Coments>
<TruckId>18971852</TruckId>
<Picture/>
</Stops>

Comment: This is sample XML

Comment: Code is exactly same as that of https://stackoverflow.com/a/56569964/7494522

Comment: @JustLudo posted the xml file

Comment: @PriyankaKadam Instead of posting it in a comment, you can also Edit your question to include it there.

Answer (score 2):

i think you are confusing attributes and tags:

Xml attributes example:

```
<Stops test="attrib1"> </Stops>
```

In your case the element root has no attribs :

`print(root.attrib) : {}`

`print(root.tag) : Stops`